# Bash: select statement doesn't break

Tags: bash

Here's a function containing a select statement that doesn't break unless you choose 'quit':

```
function func_set_branch () {
        local _file=$1
        local _expr=$2
        local _bdate=$3
        local _edate=$4
        local _mid=$(awk -F'\t' -v ref="${_expr}" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} match($0, ref) {print $5}' "$CONF")

        if (( $(grep -c . <<<"${_mid}") > 1 )); then
                mapfile -t arr <<< "${_mid}"

                PS3="Please choose an option "
                select option in "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" quit
                do
                        case $option in
                                1) _mid="${arr[0]}"; break 2;;
                                2) _mid="${arr[1]}"; break 2;;
                                quit) exit 0;;
                        esac
                done
        fi

        sed "s#{{mid}}#${_mid}#
             s#{{bdate}}#${_bdate}#
             s#{{edate}}#${_edate}#" "$_file"
}
```

I've tried different levels of `break` ..no dice. What have I missed after staring at this waaaay tooo long?

Output:

```
automation@automation-workstation2:~/scripts/branch-fines$ bash get_data.sh -f branch-fines.sql -B coulee -b 2014-01-01 -e 2014-12-31
coulee 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31
1) 472754
2) 472758
3) quit
Please choose an option 1
Please choose an option 2
Please choose an option 3
automation@automation-workstation2:~/scripts/branch-fines$
```

***UPDATE***

Working code with much thanks to rici and glenn jackman.

```
PS3="Please choose an option "
select option in "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" quit
do
    case $option in
        "${arr[0]}") MID="${arr[0]}"; break;;
        "${arr[1]}") MID="${arr[1]}"; break;;
        quit) exit 0;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: You only have 1 level to break out of, the `select` -- there are no `for` or `while` or `until` loops in that code.

Comment: I fixed that in the code I ended up with ...hadn't gotten around to posting the working version. Will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the body of the `select` statement, the specified variable (`$option` in this case) is set to the value of the selected word, not its index. That's why `quit` works; you're checking to see if `$option` is `quit`, not `3`. Similarly, you should be checking for `${arr[0]}` and `${arr[1]}` rather than `1` and `2`.

Since the array values are not `1` or `2`, no clause in the `case` statement will match, so the `case` statement will do nothing; in that case, no `break` is executed so the `select` continues looping.