# Bash menu based case esac choice with conditions

Tags: linux, bash, switch-statement

I am writing a bash script to login to the Azure cloud based on the Subscription Principal with username, Subscription ID and password, as i have to login to different subscription as when required basis and thus i decided to put them into a script and define the choice which will ask on the prompt.

I have looked around the got some help which is used as follows.

The First script works well while i'm exploring `case` `esac` with bash menu based but somewhat not able to understand it.

### First Script:

This works Just fine..

```
#!/bin/bash

function azure_login() {    

echo -e "
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
| 1.) Azure login                                |
| 2.) Azure SPN login for non-prod               |     
| 3.) Azure SPN login for prod                   |
| 4.) Quit                                       |
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"

read -e -p "Select the Choice: " choice

if [ "$choice" == "1" ]; then
    echo "logging in to the Azure..."
        az login -u kulfi.khat@xyz.com
 

elif [ "$choice" == "2" ]; then

    echo "logging in to non-prod2 evn..."
        az login --service-principal --username "some_username" --tenant "some_tenant_id"

elif [ "$choice" == "3" ]; then

        echo "logging in to prod3 evn..."
        az login --service-principal --username "another_username" --tenant "anoher_tenant_id"

elif [ "$choice" == "4" ]; then

    clear && exit 0

else

    echo "Please select 1, 2, 3, or 4." && sleep 3
    clear && azure_login

fi
}

azure_login
```

### Script Result as expected:

```
$ bash azur_login.sh

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
| 1.) Azure login                                |
| 2.) Azure SPN login for non-prod               |
| 3.) Azure SPN login for prod                   |
| 4.) Quit                                       |
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

Select the Choice: 2
logging in to non-prod2 evn...
Password:
```

### Second Script:

This script provided `menu` for selection and asked for password and them logs in and again asking back for the choice, While i want if the selected option is correct and user logged in then stay there and close the script work.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Option 4" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "logging in to the Azure..."
            az login -u kulfi.khat@xyz.com
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "logging in to prod2 evn..."
            az login --service-principal --username "some_username" --tenant "some_tenant_id"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "logging in to prod3 evn..."
            az login --service-principal --username "another_username" --tenant "another_tenant_id"  
            ;;
        "Option 4")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

### Script Result:

```
$  bash azur_login.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Option 4
5) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
logging in to the Azure...
Password:

Please enter your choice:
```

I am learning the `case` `esac` , please excuse me if there is anything which i can not explain well or not upto-date.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the closest I could get was [Bash: select statement doesn't break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28226939/5291015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked first variant but with `case`

```
#!/bin/bash
menu="
+-----------------------------------+
| 1.) Azure login                   |
| 2.) Azure SPN login for non-prod  |     
| 3.) Azure SPN login for prod      |
| 4.) Quit                          |
+-----------------------------------+

Select the Choice: "

azure_login() {
    read -rep "$menu" choice
    case             $choice in
        1) echo "logging in to the Azure..."
           az login -u kulfi.khat@xyz.com;;

        2) echo "logging in to non-prod2 evn..."
           az login --service-principal --username "some_username" --tenant "some_tenant_id";;

        3) echo "logging in to prod3 evn..."
           az login --service-principal --username "another_username" --tenant "anoher_tenant_id";;

        4) clear && exit 0;;

        *) echo "Please select 1, 2, 3, or 4." && sleep 3
           clear && azure_login;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: And now it's even better)

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right, but missed the key part of using `select` statement in generating menus. If you intention is show a menu for the user and exit the prompt after the first selection, then you should have broken out from the case statement.

The solution is to use the `break` statement which does an unconditional break out of the `select` loop. For e.g.

```
    "Option 1")
        echo "logging in to the Azure..."
        az login -u kulfi.khat@xyz.com
        break                              # to break out the 'Option 1'
        ;;
```

Similarly add that to rest of your cases. Also as a better prompt menu, consider adding the actual option string to the menu instead of leaving with `'Option..'`

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you show an example of `actual option string to the menu instead of leaving with 'Option..`

Comment: @kulfi: I meant, you could populate the menu options instead of `Option 1` with `"Option 1 - Logging in to the Azure"` and similarly for other options